# Body is not deserialize from powershell call

Tags: powershell, asp.net-web-api2

I have an error with powershell api call.

This is my powershell code :

```
$body='[{"Criteres":[{"Nom":"Code","Valeur":"lyon"},{"Nom":"Libellé","Valeur":"lyon test"}],"Nom":"X_Site_Geogr","Pseudo":"Site Géographique"}]'
$url="http://localhost/api/OccObjets/"
$Responseappli = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url -Method "PUT" -Body $body -ContentType "text/json" -UseDefaultCredentials
Write-Output $Responseappli.Content
```

This is controller method :

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody] IEnumerable<TOObjetAvecCriteres> listeOccurrence)
```

If i use the same body on Postman or swagger, it works perfectly but with powershell, my list is null.

I add a handler to get raw body with that :

```
var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<TOObjetAvecCriteres>>(bodyText);
```

body powershell :

```
"[{\"Criteres\":[{\"Nom\":\"Code\",\"Valeur\":\"lyon\"},{\"Nom\":\"Libell�\",\"Valeur\":\"lyon test\"}],\"Nom\":\"X_Site_Geogr\",\"Pseudo\":\"Site G�ographique\"}]"
```

body swagger :

```
"[{\"Criteres\":[{\"Nom\": \"Code\",\"Valeur\": \"lyon\"},{\"Nom\": \"Libellé\",\"Valeur\": \"lyon test\"}],\"Nom\": \"X_Site_Geogr\",\"Pseudo\": \"Site Géographique\"}]"
```

Deserialization in handler works whith both powershell and swagger but in my controller function, listeOccurrence variable is null with powershell.

I aslo try to write body like this an convert to json but it doesn't work :

```
$body=@(
@{
    "Nom"="X_Site_Geogr"
    "Pseudo"="Site Géographique"
    "Criteres"= @(
        @{
            "Nom"="Code"
            "Valeur"="lyon"
        }
        @{
            "Nom"="Libellé"
            "Valeur"="lyon test2"
        }
    )
}
```

)

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `�` in the body indicates an encoding problem. Make sure to save your PowerShell script as UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: thank youk, it works with paste utf8 string